# How to use same view-state with different views in spring web flow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

Hey Guys, I am trying to find the way to use same view-state but with different views so that based on where it is being called, I can provide different view to the user.

For instance, trying to achieve as follows:

`<var name="searchpage" value="search.jsp">`
`<view-state id="searchBusiness" view="${searchpage}"/>`

Please share your experience so that I can achieve this functionality easily.

Comment: You didn't put anything under "trying to achieve as follows".  An example would be nice.

Comment: just added the code. Actually posting code for the first time so didnt know how to do that. But I got it. 
Your help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use decision-state for this purpose as first state of your flow.